# How to restart mongodb from windows services

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb installed as Windows services,

after that I have updated the config file: mongod.cfg

I want to restart the services so that it can reload my configs,

how can I restart the MongoDB services?

Environment:

Windows 10

MongoDB 4.2

Installation Path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin

Comment: This is not a programming question and as such it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

Mongodb default service name is `MongoDb` you can find it in your system Services (run services.msc or search it into your searchbox-if there is any),
you can restart your server in cmd using flowing command:

```
sc start  MongoDb
```

or in powershell :

```
Start-Service -Name MongoDb
```